# How to get data from document in a parent collection based on a query in a subcollection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, filtering

Hey guys I try to get data from a document which has a Field value Name and a subcollection named `kurzwaffensub` but for my project I need to do a `collectionGroup query`  and after that I need the `Name value`  of each document which matches the query from the subcollection.

[image: My Current Structure]

So let me explain.
First I need to do a `collectionGroup query` of the `documents` from the subcollection based on their two parameter `kurzHersteller` and `kurzModell` which I marked in green at the picture.
After that I get all `Documents` of every `Subcollection` which match the query.

And as you can see the `blue document uid`  is the same `uid`  as in the fieldvalue of every document of the subcollection.

And my goal is to get the red marked `fieldvalue` of the `documents` of the main collection after the group query of the `subcollection`.

But I only want to receive the Names of the `documents` which match the requirments of the query .

So in this Case i need the Name `Felix Sturms` because he has a `document` in his `subcollection` marked in yellow
which match the Search for `kurzHersteller : Andere` and `kurzKaliber : Andere`

I dont know if this is possible or if I need to structure my data in another way. Im a beginner with firebase firestore so perhabs you can help me.

```
const [test, setTest] = useState([]);

const HEuKA = query(kurzRef,where("kurzHersteller", "==", `${kurzHersteller}` ),  where('kurzKaliber' , '==', `${kurzKaliber}`));

const handleClick = async () => {

...blablabla
...

} else if (kurzHersteller && kurzKaliber) {
        const modell = await getDocs(HeuKa);
        modell.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  setTest(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      
});
  } else { alert('Bitte etwas eingeben')}

  
}
```

So thats the first operation after I receive the array of the documents of the subcollection which match the query , i need another operation to get the corresponding documents from the parent collection which contain the information about the Name of the users which have a document in the subcollection which match the values `kurzHersteller: Andere` and `kurzModell: Andere` of this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot) from your collection group query, you can loop over every document and then access the parent document using `.parent` property present on the [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) of each document. Try running the following code after your first query:

```
const modell = await getDocs(HeuKa);

const data = [];

for (const doc of modell.docs) {
  const parentDoc = await getDoc(doc.ref.parent.parent);
  const { Name } = parentDoc.data();
  data.push({
    ...doc.data(),
    Name,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks I didnt know that was possible. But as a bloody beginner theres always something new to learn .    I will try this solution later and let you know if could implement it :)

Answer (score 1):

Firestore reads/queries return documents from a single collection, or with collection group queries from all collections with the same name. There is no way in Firestore to include data from the parent document in the same read/query.

The two options you have are:

1. Read the parent document for any result you get from the subcollection.
2. Duplicate the necessary information from the parent document in each document in the subcollection.

While #1 is the most common option for people who are new to Firestore (and NoSQL databases in general), as you get more experienced with Firestore you'll often find yourself using #2 more often too.

Comment: Thank you I thought about your second solution first but I was not sure if this would be the optimal way.  But anyway good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

I think a more robust way, where you don't depend on the structure, is to get the document from 'uid' field you have on each document you get back from the query'. Even better would be to change this field to type "reference", in which case you can just do (assuming you create a field called customerReference as a replacement for uid):

```
 modell.forEach((doc) => {
   const customerDoc = await doc.data().customerReference.get();
   const name = customerDoc.data().Name;
```

Comment: With this solution would it be possible to get a document from a different collection which has  the same fieldvalue ```customerReference``` if I want to query it ?

Comment: yes, the customerReference of type 'reference' can point to any collection, It contains the full path to the document.

Comment: Thank you thats important to know. I may face this problem in the near future then i will probably need your help again :D I marked the other comment as the right one because of this specific problem. But your solution is as right as the others.

Comment: Hey buddy  its me again . I  tried to use your solution but it seems as I'm to dumb to get the job done perhabs you can help me again I posted a new question in detail. Perhabs you can point me in the right direction . Would be very glad :)